# Convert csv file into DynamoDB json format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I have +7 million records stored in CSV file hosted at AWS S3 bucket and I want to load them into DynamoDB table. I've tried data ***AWS pipeline service*** but the job always failed, because this service doesn't support importing CSV format.
So I should first convert CSV data into format that can be understood by DynamoDB. Is there any way to make this conversion?

Comment: Hi @Jaco or anyone... do you have an answer to this question?

Comment: Would a custom Python script be a suitable solution ? I am not sure there is an off the shelf solution for this.

Comment: This is just data translation.  A simple to write script should take care of this pretty easily.

Answer (score -2):

AWS Datapipeline service supports CSV Import to dynamo db. You can create a pipeline from the aws console for datapipeline and choose "Import DynamoDB backup data from S3." to import CSV stored in S3 to Dynamodb.

See also

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html#DataPipelineExportImport.Importing

Comment: That template assumes the data you're importing is from a DynamoDB export – which is definitely not in CSV format.

Comment: Just the first line (describing csv column) is different. Other data rows should be the same.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  DynamoDB expects the backup file to be in a specific JSON format particular to DynamoDB.  You are not able to import a CSV directly into Dynamo.  You can import a CSV into Redshift.